# Design outline for console rouglike interface

Tags: command-line-interface, ncurses, roguelike

I am looking for a way to organize the interface following the rougelike pattern (term borrowed from *The Art of Unix Programming* by Eric S. Raymond), which is basically similar to that of vim, links etc. I opt for C++ with ncurses and cdk.

I have already peeked at the source of [wicd-curses](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/) (rougelike interface for wicd). There is a main window object which processes keystrokes and invokes actions. If a new screen was opened (say, options screen), the main window delegates the keystrokes to an appropriate OptionsWindow object. The view part was kind of mixed with a controller part of the application.

I would really like to know the proper, oo design of a rougelike app interface. How to organize my screens (windows)? In which component should I process the keystrokes? What about things common to all the windows (moving focus, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

A good book for this is [Using C With Curses, Lex, and Yacc: Building a Window Shell for Unix System V by 
Axel-Tobias Schreiner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139328645) (also the author of Object-Oriented Programming in C, [link](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/)).

Comment: I've already seen you praise this book somewhere on SO; and I'll definitely try to get it (my faculty has one, but in German...). I'm a little anxious that books from 'the days' might not follow today's standards like oo paradigm or design patterns, but still looks like a good read. Thanks!